# getting the partition number in a reducer to which a key-value pair belongs

Tags: mapreduce

when i am processing a given key-{set of values} pair in reducer function, how can I get the partition number to which this key-{set of values} belong to? How is it possible to get this partition number without adding extra information about the partition number with each key-value pair during partitioning?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This has worked for me:
jobconf.getInt( "mapred.task.partition",  0);
in the reducer.